# Iterating a multi-dimensional array and mixing it

Tags: php

im trying to mix my multi dimension arrays, and it iterates fine, but the output isnt what im trying to accomplish, i need to mix the values.

array= [ [ p ,t ,j ] , [ 9 , 3 , 6 ] ];

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {       
        echo $val;      
    }
}
}
```

array output: p,9,t,3,j,6 //should be
Mine is: p,t,j,9,3,6

Comment: Consider using [SPL MultipleIterator](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php), or transposing and then looping as you're doing; or looping one array, and using the key from that to access the same entry in the other

Comment: do the arrays always appear in the same format? a parent array with two child arrays the first with letters and the second with integers? does the parent array ever have something other than arrays as children?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach

```
foreach($array[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value, $array[1][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by 'mix' do you mean trying to combine the secondary arrays into one long array? If that is the case:

```
$finalArray = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
  $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, $value);
}
```

edit: now that I look at it, I didn't quite echo the output like you needed, but the output should be in the correct order in the `$finalArray`  and this should work with any amount of inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you this is your answer:

```
   //creat an empty array to save the new result
   $result= array();
   //do this for incrementing
   $i=0; 
   //your arrays here and looping it
   $array=array(array( p ,t ,j ) , array( 9 , 3 , 6 ) );

   foreach($array as $a){
    if(is_array($a)){
   foreach($a as $b){
       $result[$i]= $b;
       }//end foreach
     }else{
     $result[$i]= $a;
    }//end else
   $i++;

   }//end foreach
//then print_r to show your array
print_r($result);
```

have a nice day ^_^